# How to solve GoRouter.routeInformationProvider missing error?

Tags: flutter

The flutter team has given the following flutter project created by them, to learn from. https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/tree/main/boring_to_beautiful
through their [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-boring-to-beautiful#2).

I cloned the repo and tried to start the app. But it throws the following error.

*════════ Exception caught by widgets library
The following assertion was thrown building IconTheme(color: Color(0xdd000000)):
This GoRouteInformationParser needs to be used with GoRouteInformationProvider, did you forget to pass in GoRouter.routeInformationProvider to the Router constructor?
'package:go_router/src/go_route_information_parser.dart':
package:go_router/src/go_route_information_parser.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 148 pos 13: 'routeInformation is DebugGoRouteInformation'*

From this error msg, I could understand that 'routeInformationProvider' seems to be missing. But is that possible in a working demo project given by the flutter team to learn from? Should I pass the routeInformationProvider? if so any docs, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: - This should not be marked as the correct answer, as it was just a workaround. Please mark Luca Iaconelli answer as the correct one

Previous answer:
*Just go back to version 3.1.1 of GoRouter. It seems latest version has an issue*

Comment: This is not an "issue" it is a breaking change of the latest version of go_router. You now need to pass a routeInformationProvider to the router, very simple change.

Answer (score 35):

Just add routeInformationProvider to MaterialApp.router.

Example:

```
  final _router = GoRouter(
         ...
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp.router(
          routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
          ...
       );
   }
```

Comment: Off my God, this error took more than 2 hours to resolve. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I also had this problem, but with the `go_router version: ^4.1.0` and following this [guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T2LmzMj5HpD7hEexXL4Xz6vqoJD81bEGaa9NsV24faw/edit?resourcekey=0-PuQbtDVl7ZabpJ2B9AHWUg) the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Add `routeinformationProvider` at `MaterialApp` root:

```
MaterialApp.router(
  routeInformationProvider: goRouter.routeInformationProvider,//Add this line
  routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
  routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was solved when I added

the following line of code

```
routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
```

before the following two lines of codes

```
routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
```

Answer (score 1):

adding `routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,` in addition to `routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser, routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,` solved my problem.